# Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code: Is there a "run chapter" shortcut like in GoogleColab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using Jupyter Notebooks to programm in python and before I switched to VS Code I used Google Colab. In Google Colab you have the function to run all cells in a chapter you created with a markdown cell, but I could not find a way to make this work in VS Code.

Is there any way to do this without manually selecting all cells inside that chapter?